# Java Matching multiple tokens with Regex

Tags: java, regex, token

I found a regular expression which matches tokens surrounded with {} but it only seems find the first found item.

How can the following code be changed so that all of the tokens will be found rather than just {World}, would i need to use loops?

```
// The search string
String str = "Hello {World} this {is} a {Tokens} test";

// The Regular expression (Finds {word} tokens)
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");

// Match the string with the pattern
Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);

// If results are found
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(m.groupCount()); // 1
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // {World}
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // World (Get without {})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your code you just do one match, and get the groups captured in that single match.

If you want to get the other matches, you have to continue matching in a loop until `find()` returns false.

So basically all you need is to replace `if` with `while` and you're there.

Comment: Thanks this works great, just wondering is there a easy way to to get the total amount of matches? Or would the best way be to add each found item in the while loop to a total variable?

Answer (score 4):

The [`groupCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29) method doesn't return the number of matches, it returns  the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern. You defined one group in your pattern, hence this method returns 1.

You can find a next match to your pattern by calling `find()` again; it will attempt to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. When it returns `false`, you'll know there are no more matches.

Thus, you should iterate through your matches like this:

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer from biziclop as it gave me the solution i needed but thank you for the explanation. This was very useful to know also.